# Chrome Single Page Application Page Load Issue

Tags: google-chrome, vuejs2, single-page-application

I am experiencing page loading issues on chrome on multiple platforms.. The problem is that web page is partially loaded and unloaded parts sometimes disappear if I hover mouse over them. See the image below for clarification. Can you help with this? My website's url is https://serkanozel.me and this issue occurs at blog tab, namely at this url https://serkanozel.me/blog And screensheets are from that url.

I tested this with Windows 10 64 bit and Ubuntu 18.04 and having issues on both. I tested with Firefox too. Problem does not occur on Firefox.

EDIT: I get this issue 80 percent of the time. I tried uninstalling all my extensions and trying. I tried uninstalling chrome and trying with a fresh chrome installation. Still the same issue exists. 
EDIT2: I tried on chromium, on ubuntu 18.04. Same issue happens.

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

Comment: I tried to load the blog tab, and it is working fine for me. so is it always happening to you?

Comment: Yes 80 percent of the time with chrome

Comment: Maybe due to one of my extensions... I will try removing them one by one. EDIT: Still no luck :S. Removed all the extensions and tried again, still the same. I will try installing chrome again